# Store the result for for-loop

Tags: matlab

I have the following data: `ET = [1 3 5 7 6 4]`, and below is my code:

```
for i=1:3
    meanET(i)=ET(:,1+(2*i-2)); %//for i=1,extract ET column 1 data
    stdET(i)=ET(:,2+(2*i-2)); 
    totalET(i)=meanET(i)+stdET(i)
end
```

However, MATLAB display's an error that says that in the assignment `A(I)=B`, the number of elements in B and I must be the same, and therefore I modified my code to this:

```
for i=1:3
    meanET=ET(:,1+(2*i-2));%for i=1,extract ET column 1 data
    stdET=ET(:,2+(2*i-2)); 
    totalET=meanET+stdET
end
```

After running the latter code, it showed `meanET=6`, `stdET=4`, and `totalET=10`, which means that it only stored the data for i=3 in the workspace. I want to get the result like 
`totalET=[4 12 10]` in the workspace, corresponding to `i = 1, 2, 3`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should just declare your target array at the beginning of your code:

```
meanET=zeros(size(ET,1),3);
stdET=zeros(size(ET,1),3);
for i=1:3
   meanET(:,i)=ET(:,1+(2*i-2));
   stdET(:,i)=ET(:,2+(2*i-2)); 
end
totalET=meanET+stdET
```

Comment: what is the meaning of type meanET=zeros(size(ET,1),1)??

Comment: (it should be 3, I edited that) it tells matlab that you are going to store that vector/matrix with those dimensions. It's not completely necessary as matlab would allow your vector to grow but it's better as no extra memory operations are needed during execution)

Answer (score 3):

OR you could just go with a simple vectorized solution:

```
>> totalET = ET(1:2:5) + ET(2:2:6)

totalET =
    4   12   10
```